# Error: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

so the gist is this. I want to create a trigger, that when an employee's id in the **Employees** table changes, I want it to change in the child-tables as well, more specifically in the **Drivers** and **Radiomen** tables. Obviously both of these have the primary key from **Employees** as a foreign key. So the code I wrote is something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_employee_id
AFTER UPDATE OF id_employee ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    UPDATE radiomen SET employees_id_employee = :NEW.id_employee WHERE employees_id_employee  = :OLD.id_employee
    UPDATE drivers SET employees_id_employee = :NEW.id_employee WHERE employees_id_employee  = :OLD.id_employee;
END;
```

Now I don't want there to be any confusion because I muddled the naming of certain attributes. employees_id_employee is the name of the foreign keys present in both the **Radiomen** and **Drivers** table. After creating the trigger, when I try to use the following statement, I get the deadlock error.

```
UPDATE employees SET id_employee=13 WHERE name='Wick' AND surname='John';
```

I know that this error occurs when the program is accessing the same information twice or something like that. But I don't know why that would be the cause, because my UPDATE statement is referencing solely the **Employees** table, and the trigger activates when this happens and only makes changes in either the **Radiomen** or the **Drivers** table, depending on where said employee was assigned to. In that case, why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the primary key continuously using triggers is generally not a good practice, in my opinion.

Your trigger works if you remove the pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION.
Otherwise, the updates on the radiomen and drivers tables run in their own transaction, but access a resource from the main transaction (to validate the foreign key) that is being changed.

---

I tried to reproduce your setup. Please tell me if yours is different.

```
CREATE TABLE employees
( id_employee NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(100),
  surname VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE radiomen
( id_radiomen NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  employees_id_employee NUMBER REFERENCES employees (id_employee)
);

CREATE TABLE drivers
( id_drivers NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  employees_id_employee NUMBER REFERENCES employees (id_employee)
);


INSERT INTO employees VALUES (10, 'Wick', 'John');
INSERT INTO radiomen VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO drivers VALUES (1, 10);


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_employee_id
AFTER UPDATE OF id_employee ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    --PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    UPDATE radiomen SET employees_id_employee = :NEW.id_employee WHERE employees_id_employee  = :OLD.id_employee;
    UPDATE drivers SET employees_id_employee = :NEW.id_employee WHERE employees_id_employee  = :OLD.id_employee;
END;
/

UPDATE employees SET id_employee=13 WHERE name='Wick' AND surname='John';

SELECT * FROM radiomen;
SELECT * FROM drivers;
```

---

Even though it worked in this example, it is not the right way. Think about what you are doing and adjust your model.

Comment: Well I wanted to do one of those triggers that has the main purpose of dealing with these referential restrictions. I did not use it because I thought it was necessary personally, but it is mandatory to use one of these for the project I am working on. And if I remove the PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;, I will get an error that the table is mutating and will still not be able to run the UPDATE statement.

Comment: Yes, Sir, that's pretty much my setup. The only exception is that I make the employee John Wick only a driver. He is not in the Radiomen table. In the trigger I also put an "UPDATE radiomen" in case I want to update an id of someone who has that job eventually.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this. It is a very very bad idea. There is **absolutely no reason to ever change the primary key**. If anything put a trigger on the table which throws an exception if an update of the PK is attempted.

Comment: @Ciuboss Are there other triggers on these tables?

Comment: @ThomasKirchhoff, none. I'm quite confused about why I am receiving this error. Maybe something from sqlDeveloper itself and how the settings are made regarding data tables. Because from the code itself I've searched far and wide and don't really have any "solutions" left to try.

Comment: @Belayer, well I needed to do such a table where in case a piece of information is changed, there is a set of information that needs to change mandatory in the child table. And using the keys is the most direct way of doing this. I don't really have many attributes that would need to change in cascade other than the keys.

Comment: @Ciuboss I've picked out a link from Ask Tom for help. Maybe you will find answers here. 
[link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5773459616034)

Comment: @ThomasKirchhoff, ya thanks anyway for the assistance. I'll try looking at your link and see what turns up. Have a good one!